# React forwardRef: ref and other props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref, react-forwardref

A parent component:

```js
const Parent = (props) => {
  const ref = useRef();

  return <Child ref={ref} />
}
```

and the child:

```js
const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <button ref={ref} ...>click</button>
})
```

What if I want to pass more props to `Child` than just `ref`?

I've searched documents and tutorials, but found nothing; and by trial-and-error, I guess this would work:

```js
// in parent
<Child onClick={...} prop1={...} prop2={...} ref={ref} />
```

and then in `Child`, I can get these props (`onClick`, `prop1`, `prop2`) from `props`.

Is that all I need to do? By putting `ref` as the last prop passing to the child?

What if I have more than one button in `Child` that needs a `ref`?

Comment: Props will receive multiple values you put on child in parent component, follow the first comment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// in parent
<Child onClick={...} prop1={...} prop2={...} ref={ref} />
```

The order is irrelevant. `forwardRef` extracts the ref prop from the properties and creates a wrapper.

The other props are available in `props` (the first argument in the `forwardRef` callback-function)

If you want to use multiple refs you can use the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53818443/3554135).

Answer (score 3):

Well, i had followed this approach,

Parent component

```
const Parent = (props) => {
  const ref = useRef();

  return <Child _ref={ref} />
}
```

Child component

```
const Child = forwardRef(({ _ref, prop1, prop2, prop3, ...props }) => {
  return <button ref={_ref} ...>click</button>
})
```

And it worked

Answer (score 0):

In Typescript, you can pass props as below

Parent Component

```
const Parent = (props) => {
  <SnackBarComponent
    ref={childRef}
    data={['soap', 'sponge']}
  />
}
```

Child Component

```
interface ISnackBar {
  data: Array<string>;
}

const SnackBarComponent = forwardRef(({data}: ISnackBar, ref) => {
return(<Text>{data}</Text>)

})
```