# useRef not working as expected in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that handles user authentication and displays a login form if needed, otherwise just displays the children.

```js
function AuthWrapper({children}){
  let [auth, setAuth] = React.useState(null);
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    // Do stuff to check or change state
  }, []);
  let component = (<>Loading...</>);
  if(auth){
    component = (<>{children}</>);
  }
  return component;
}
```

Then I use it in another component where I need to access stuff in the DOM with a `ref`.

```js
function App(props) {
  let inputRef = React.useRef();
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('currentRef', inputRef.current);
  }, []);
  return (
    <AuthWrapper>
      <input placeholder='Enter your name' ref={inputRef} />
    </AuthWrapper>
  );
}
```

Problem is, obviously, there's nothing in the DOM to reference at the time the `useEffect` is called because the `AuthWrapper` hasn't rendered the children yet. Therefore, `inputRef.current` is always undefined.

I *kind of* understand the problem, but every solution I've tried has either failed or just felt really gross and hacky. What are some best practices or clean solutions for setting my reference to a DOM element that doesn't render immediately, and then accessing it once it does render?

Here's an online code playground demo: https://playcode.io/1769946

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63654553/16770846) answer your question?

Comment: At any given time, will only one component be provided as `children`?

Comment: No, that's not quite the same issue, but interesting thread, thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the `useEffect` with a `useCallback` and then using the callback to set the reference was the correct solution, and appears to be best practice when dealing with references in general.

Something like this...

```js
const myRef = useRef();
useEffect(()=>{
  myRef.current.addEventListener('click', myFunct);
  return ()=>myRef.current.removeEventListener('click', myFunct);
}, [myRef]);
return <button ref={myRef}>Click me</button>
```

is better written as

```js
const myRef = useRef();
const setMyRef = useCallback(ele=>{
  if(myRef.current){
    // The ref already had a value
    // Do some cleanup here
    myRef.current.removeEventListener('click', myFunct);
  }
  if(ele){
    // a node has been passed, 
    // assign it to the reference 
    // and do whatever I need to with the node
    myRef.current = ele;
    myRef.current.addEventListener('click', myFunct);
  }
});
return <button ref={setMyRef}>Click me</button>
```

The post that cleared it up for me was [here](https://medium.com/@teh_builder/ref-objects-inside-useeffect-hooks-eb7c15198780).

Comment: Is this a contrived example or is it real? Manually adding click handlers to a ref when you could just use the onClick prop

Comment: @AdamJenkins - IRL I'm listening for a custom Bootstrap event that's fired when a tab is changed.

Answer (score 0):

By default React does not let a component access the DOM nodes of other components. You will have to go through the `parent` first (in this case that is `AuthWrapper`). You give the `reference`(s) to the `parent` then the `parent` makes the attachment for you to the specific `child`(ren). For example:

```
function App(props) {
  let inputRef = React.useRef();
  /* ••• */
  return (
    <AuthWrapper ref={inputRef}>
      <input placeholder='Enter your name' />
    </AuthWrapper>
  );
}
```

Now `AuthWrapper` i.e. the `parent` is solely responsible for how it lets external routines access it’s `child`(ren). This design principle is part of a general attempt to have complete component encapsulation. We will now rewrite `AuthWrapper` as follows:

```
const AuthWrapper = React.forwardRef((props, elementRef) => {
  let [auth, setAuth] = React.useState(null);
  /* ••• */
  let component = (<>Loading...</>);
  if(auth){
    component = Children.map(props.children, child => React.cloneElement(child, { ref: elementRef });
  }
  return component;
}
```

If there will be more than one `child`, you will use multiple `ref`s. I would recommend [using `useImperativeHandle` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61388453/16770846).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not trying to access the ref from the parent element.

Comment: You misunderstood. The `ref` has to be provided to the parent element. It is the parent that will handle `ref` attachment. You cannot give `ref` directly to the inner `node` of a custom element like you did in the OP.

Comment: No, I get what you're suggesting, it's just bad code and I don't wanna do it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Have a look at the gigantic red warning on the [man page for `cloneElement`](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement).